# Let f(z) be analytic on the unit disk D.f(r) = max{| f(z)| : |z| = r}. Does f'(r) > 0, if f is not a constant?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be analytic on the unit disk $D.$

$f(r) = \max\{| f(z)| : |z| = r\}.$
Why $f'(r) > 0,$ if $f$ is not a constant.

And why if $f(0) = 0,$ then $r f ′
(r) \geq f(r)$ and the equality holds if and only if $f(z) = cz$ for
some nonnegative constant $c.$

It looks familiar but I just cannot recall any theorem dealing with this.

Comment: You should use a different name, e.g. $g(r)$ instead of $f(r)$ because $f$ is already the given analytic function.

Answer (score 0):

For harmonic functions:

1. because the maximum is always on the boundary
2. is a monotonicity formula: you obtain it by comparing the Dirichlet energy of your function with the Dirichlet energy of the 1-homogeneous function with the same value on a circle.

For analytic functions you know that real and imaginary part are harmonic... don't know if this is the best way to obtain these informations.

Comment: I was about to write something like this, but got stuck at the point where I wanted to state that $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dr}\max\{\,|f(z)|: |z|=r\,\}$ exists in the first place. Is there a simple argument for that?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I am also stuck at this point.Have you got any idea?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I guess f(r) is not another function.The problem just means that f(z) attains it's maximum at z=r.